# PHP do not parse array input name

Tags: php, input

Let's say that I have the following simple input text box:

```
<input type="text" name="Details[0]->Name" value="" />
```

Now the problem is, php translating the input name as array, and then ignore the rest name after the closing square bracket. So in print_r, it become:

```
Details => Array{
    [0] => "Input"
}
```

What can I do to workaround this? Is there any unparsed `$_REQUESTS`?

N.B: If you noticed it, yes I am trying to use automatic input to class mapper as it has been done in Asp.net mvc.

Edit:

The additional solution requirement is that I can read raw array input from either GET, POST or multipart form requests.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446989/get-the-raw-request-using-php ?

Comment: Or using `<?php $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); ?> `?

Comment: @enigma file_get_contents only work on post requests I presume? I cannot get it to work on GET requests

Comment: And I don't really understand those who downvote without giving any reason

Answer (score 1):

For `POST`:

```
echo urldecode ( file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

For `GET`:

```
echo urldecode ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Both the above give the output `Details[0]->Name=testval`

As for `enctype='multipart/form-data'`, the unparsed data is not available in php. However, there is a solution of sorts given by this SO question: [Get raw post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361673/get-raw-post-data)

Comment: I replied at your comment. Is file_get_contents works on other requests header other than POST? And I also want it to work on enc-multipart form

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am still waiting for some way that do not required to edit the initial config file.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace Input with some another name like Inputcust and make new array

```
Details => Array{
[0] => "Inputcust"
```

}

and where ever you want to use again replace from Inputcust => Input

Comment: You are getting me wrong. I am translating the input name to PHP syntax (without eval though). So in short, I am telling PHP to do this code `$result->Details[0]->Name = $inputValue` when getting input with name `Details[0]->Name`.

Comment: so you can convert array to object.