# httpful POST request: get raw HTTP message

Tags: php, http, httpful

I use httpful to post a message:

```
try
{
    $ret = \Httpful\Request::post($url)
            ->addHeaders(array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ))
            ->body("mystring=".urlencode($msg))
            ->send();
} catch (Exception $e)
{
    trigger_error("Exception :".$e->getMessage()."\n");
}
```

The system on the other side cannot read it and also cannot put out debug information - how can you get the raw HTTP message (including headers, separators, etc.) that is actually sent?

Comment: I’d try and send that to a script of my own first in a case like this, and use something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/48653050/10955263 to see what is received. If that works / looks like you’d expect it to, then the problem must rather be on the receiving end, or the way there (proxies, rewriting, etc. might interfere?)

Comment: That solution relies on `getallheaders` and does also a lot of reconstruction. That's not really useful when debugging, especially when the issue is about encoding, line-endings, etc. etc.

Comment: For example the solutions reconstruct the separator between header and body by just putting out two newlines. Who knows what was really sent? Maybe some carriage-return was sent but later filtered out, etc. etc.

Comment: Well then feel free to wireshark the whole thing, or something like that …

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446989/get-the-raw-request-using-php

Answer (score 1):

```php
try {
    $url = 'https://httpbin.org/post1'; // hasErrors
//    $url = 'https://httpbin.org1/post'; // ConnectionErrorException
    $msg = 'qwe';
    $req = \Httpful\Request::post($url)
                           ->addHeaders([
                               'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                           ])
                           ->body('mystring=' . urlencode($msg));
    $res = $req->send();

    if ($res->hasErrors()) {
        print_r("
            <pre>
            *** REQUEST ***             
            Headers: {$req->raw_headers}
            Body: {$req->payload}
            
            
            *** RESPONSE ***  
            Headers: {$res->raw_headers}
            Body: <xmp>{$res->raw_body}</xmp>
            </pre>           
        ");
    }

} catch (\Httpful\Exception\ConnectionErrorException $e) {
    if (isset($req)) {
        print_r("
            <pre>
            *** REQUEST ***             
            Headers: {$req->raw_headers}
            Body: {$req->payload}                                 
            </pre>           
        ");
    }
    if (isset($res)) {
        print_r("
            <pre>
            *** RESPONSE ***  
            Headers: {$res->raw_headers}
            Body: <xmp>{$res->raw_body}</xmp>
            </pre>
        ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get what was *actually* sent, I feel that the most reliable way is to access the data which has actually been sent, i.e., **after** it has been sent. Otherwise you'll never be *really* sure.

To do this, you can intercept the HTTP stream or, to make things easier, you can trick the server into resolving the URL to what is actually a proxy. With the appropriate certificates or instruction to trust same, you can get access to the whole request as well as the whole response, plus timings, raw data, the works.

I usually employ a custom HTTPS MitM module to do this, but there are several alternatives (just google "logging https proxy") - one I just found is [MockServer](https://mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html#start_mockserver), which seems to support several scenarios.